# Hive create role and give grant access to limited tables

Tags: hive, sql-grant

I have created a Hive database HR, which has 3 tables person, dept, contact.I have two users for HR -ad1 and us1. ad1-Admin us1-User. I want us1 to access only contact table and nothing else. How do I go about it in Hive?
This is what I tried:

```
1) Logged into Hive as ad1
2) Executed set hive.security.authorization.enabled=true;
3) create role r1
4) grant select on table contact to role r1;
5) grant role r1 to user us_1
```

Now when I log into Hive as us_1, I'm still able to query all tables

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to handle security in Hive is via Unix POSIX. Secure the unix folder where Hive stores data, and you will secure access